# Qt compiling error 1

Tags: c++, qt4

When i try to compile my program i get this

```
error: [tmp/moc/debug_shared/moc_window.cpp] Error 1
```

I have a class called Window. when I comment the Q_OBJECT line it compiles, but I can't use any slots.

```
class Window : public QWidget {
  // Q_OBJECT
public:
  Window();
public slots:
  void update();
};
```

I have QT 4.7 installed.

Any Idea why it doesn't compile when I uncomment the Q_OBJECT line?
Thanks for any help.

Comment: Oh I forgot to write that my class Window is a subclass of QWidget

Comment: Please post the whole error message, not just the last line.

Answer (score 1):

You have a `slot` so you must have the `Q_OBJECT` macro, after adding this do a clean build. And in case of an error, post the whole error log not the last line.

Answer (score 0):

maybe something is wrong with Moc paths... make sure that you have write rights in folder you use for moc-ing qt headers. ( tmp/moc/debug_shared/ ).
And I don't know this extractly for linux, but on windows directory where you generating moc files must exist.